# ElasticBeanstalk Support for Custom DB running on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Can someone please tell me if its possible to connect the ElasticBeanstalk environemnt to my DB which is running on Ec2 instance. I know that Beanstalk supports RDS but was unable to find any supporting documents which states that we can connect custom DB running on Ec2 with beanstalk environment . I am in process of automating this via cloudformation . Canyone please help .

Answer (score 0):

As long as your EB instances **have network connectivity** to your custom database (e.g. EC2 instance with the DB is in same VPC as EB instances or internet connection) then there are no reasons why you couldn't use EB with a custom database.

The connection to the database is handled by your application. EB environment in itself is not involved in the connection.

The process would be **similar** to using [external RDS with EB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/rds-external-ec2classic.html), in a sense that you could still use EB environmental variables to provide database connectivity information (db hostname to connect to, port, db name to use, ...) to your EB instances.

The only thing to ensure is that you can connect from your EB instances to the instance having your database. This generally involves setting up **security groups** if both EB instances and database instance are in **same VPC**. If they are in different VPC then have to either use internet to endure link between the instances or vpc-peering.